FormData has Data on JS but in Servlet no
I have the next code in JS:
$('.upload-button').on('click', function() {
        var fileInput = $(this).closest("div").find("input")[0].files[0]; //Aqui tengo el file
        if (!fileInput) {
            alert("Por favor, seleccione un archivo.");
            return;
        }
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', fileInput);
        formData.append("operacion", "guardarFichero");


        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: '/intranet/OperacionesMantenimientosServlet',
          data: formData,
          dataType: 'text', // Esperar una respuesta en formato JSON
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,        
          success: function(response) {
              // Manejo de la respuesta exitosa
              alert(response);
              for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
                console.log(pair[0]+', '+pair[1]);
              }
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              // Manejo de errores
              console.error('Error: ' + error);
              alert(xhr.responseText);
              for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
                console.log(pair[0]+', '+pair[1]);
              }
              //alert('Hubo un problema al enviar los datos.');
          }
        });
      });

The JSP is like that:
<div>
                        <input type="file" id="documentoPresupuestoVerFechas" class="inputLoad"/>
                        <label for="documentoPresupuestoVerFechas" class="file-label">Seleccionar Presupuesto</label>
                        <span id="nombrePresupuesto" class="file-name truncated-text">No se ha seleccionado ningún archivo</span>
                        <button class="upload-button" id="">Subir</button>
                        <button class="upload-button">Descargar</button>
                    </div>

And the Servlet in Java:
.
.
.
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*; //Para los ficheros

public class OperacionesMantenimientosServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void init() throws ServletException {
       // Do required initialization
    }

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int id_elemento = -1;
        int id_incidencia = -1;
        String jsonResponse;

        Gson gson;

String operacion = request.getParameter("operacion");

 if (operacion!=null )
            {
.
.
.
}
else{



Map<String, String[]> parametros = request.getParameterMap();

                // Recorrer todos los parámetros y mostrarlos en la consola
                out.print("No se ha seleccionado ninguna operación. a" +parametros.size());
                out.flush();
}

I was expecting that in the Servlet I found the parameter Operacion and its not null, but it always give me null. I think that maybe the formData is null, so I put a for to check it, but it gives me that it has data:
file, [object File]
operacion, guardarFichero

So the formData is filled with the file and the operacion. I cant check it if the AJAX has inside the data because is a POST, but when I try to get it on the server side, calling request.gerParameter("operacion") it gives me null.
I dont know why it has no data in the server side. Another AJAX calls in the application has de data but instead of using new FormData(), I use the serialize() of a form, but in this case, i have no form.
Anyone knows what is happening here?

How do you want to get the data at the server side if you submit a form but without setting an encoding type of it? Do you want a servlet container to guess a data structure in the http request?
